# Custom HTML select option with Angular 7 is not working

Tags: angular, angular7, dropdown, select-options

Today I am trying to make a custom select dropdown with Angular 7 and it's working fine when i putting static value in select options. But problem is when I am trying to use Angular *ngFor loop or *ngIf, Then the customisation is not working. Please see my HTML, CSS and Javascript code below.

**HTML Working**

```
<select class="selectOp" id="creator">
    <option value="hide">Select Creator</option>
    <option value="2010">Adam</option>
    <option value="2011">Imran</option>
    <option value="2012">Salma</option>
    <option value="2013">Noor</option>
    <option value="2014">Jamal</option>
    <option value="2015">Hasan</option>
  </select>
```

**HTML Not Working in Angular *ngFor**

```
<select class="selectOp">
  <option *ngFor="let contentype of dataScoruc.contentype">
    {{contentype}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dropDownFunc();
  }

  dropDownFunc(){

    $('.selectOp').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

        $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
        $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
        $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

        var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
        $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

        var $list = $('<ul />', {
            'class': 'select-options'
        }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
            $('<li />', {
                text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
                rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
            }).appendTo($list);
        }

        var $listItems = $list.children('li');

        $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
        });

        $listItems.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
            $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
            $list.hide();
            //console.log($this.val());
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
            $list.hide();
        });

    });
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.select-styled {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.select-styled:after {
  content:"";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: #4D4D4D transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.select-options {
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dededf;
  border-radius: 4px;

}
.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.select-options li:hover {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
}
.select-options li [rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Please everybody check it and put your suggestion please.

Comment: Could you please share the content of the object `dataScoruc ` that you are using in your loop  `*ngFor="let contentype of dataScoruc.contentype` ?

Comment: dataScoruc={
    contentype:[
      'AAAAA',
      'BBBB',
      'CCCC',
      'DDDD',
      'EEEE',
      'FFFFF',
    ]
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery code is executing before angular rendering its `option` tags

you need to call `this.dropDownFunc()` after angular finish it's rendering job, so you can call it from `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

in order to use  `ngAfterViewInit` you may need to import its interface from `@angular/core`

`import { Component ,  AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';`

and implements it with `AppComponent` class

`export class AppComponent  extends Component implements AfterViewInit{`

Here full source code

```
import { Component ,  AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import $ from "jquery";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  extends Component implements AfterViewInit{
  dataScoruc={
    contentype:[
      'AAAAA',
      'BBBB',
      'CCCC',
      'DDDD',
      'EEEE',
      'FFFFF',
    ]
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.dropDownFunc();
  }
   ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.dropDownFunc();
  }



  dropDownFunc(){

    $('.selectOp').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

        $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
        $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
        $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

        var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
        $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

        var $list = $('<ul />', {
            'class': 'select-options'
        }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
            $('<li />', {
                text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
                rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
            }).appendTo($list);
        }

        var $listItems = $list.children('li');

        $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
        });

        $listItems.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
            $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
            $list.hide();
            //console.log($this.val());
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
            $list.hide();
        });

    });
  }
}
```

and working demo (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jq-dummy-select)

Comment: Thank's Sajan for your help. It's working fine with the dumy data like:     
testar_test:any = [
        {
            title:"D1",
            arr:["0","1","2"]
        },
        {
            title:"D2",
            arr:["0","1","2"]
        },
        {
            title:"D3",
            arr:["0","1","2"]
        }
    ]

But when i am trying to load same structural data from API then it's not working properly.

Comment: call this.dropDownFunc() after value updated in dataScoruc.contentype

Comment: I did it but not working it. Maybe the option is not replace by li. Please click on the link for see a screen short. 
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qw7gj9o5mtum_CHQRpJtNto8zv6ywFuO)